# how to check the request is https in app engine python

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.x

I would like to know if is there a way to validate that a request (say a POST or a GET) was made over https,

I need to check this in a *webapp2.RequestHandler* to invalidate every request that is not sent via https

best regards

Answer (score 1):

Check the self.request.environ['HTTPS'] == 'on' # or 'off'.
If you only use https, consider using `secure:always` in your `app.yaml` as follows:

```
handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: main.app
  secure: always
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided above to use the app.yaml config works well but in some case you need the granularity of checking this your python code itself, which is I believe what you asked for since you want to check in the RequestHandler.

Here is what you can do inside your RequestHandler:

```
if self.request.scheme.lower() != 'https':
    self.abort(403)
else:
    # handle your request here, you know it's secured!
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using GAE Flex (where the `secure:` directive doesn't work), the only way I've found to detect this (to redirect http->https myself) is to check if `request.environ['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https'`